# Making a Cocoapod- How to create groups that XCode sees?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm putting together a cocoapod with around 20 files, some of them extensions, others config files, others real source code. I have them in subfolders, but this distinction doesn't make it's way to XCode when I import the pod. Is there a way to make a folder an XCode group?

What my Cocoapod looks like:

`/src
  /classes
     Foo.h
     Foo.m
  /extensions
     NSData+Ext.h
     NSData+Ext.m`

What it looks like in XCode now (I want it to look like the above):

```
/MyPod (Group)
  Foo.h
  Foo.m
  NSData+Ext.h
  NSData+Ext.m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently a way to do this. If you'd like this to be discussed as an addition you should submit an issue on the [main repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods)